# How to get hive date at start of day?

Tags: hive

Given a date : `2016-01-08 12:15:12`

I would like to transform it to `2016-01-08 00:00:00`

How can I get this result in hive ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the substr function to get the date and then concatenate  the 00:00:00.

```
select concat(substr('2016-01-08 12:15:12',1,10),' 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trunc(timestamp, string unit)
```

**Source**: [trunc](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_datetime_functions.html)

Purpose: Strips off fields and optionally rounds a TIMESTAMP value.
If you cast the result of TRUNC() to STRING, you will often see zeroed-out portions such as 00:00:00 in the time field.

```
cast(trunc(2016-01-08 12:15:12,'HH') as varchar(20))
```